# Cannot remove iOS simulator receipt files from Trash

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-simulator

I was trying to use the iOS7 simulator in El Capitan in Xcode 6.4, deleted it, reinstalled it etc. Part of that was dragging `iOS 7.1.simruntime` from `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` to Trash. Now I want to empty the Trash and it does not work.

1. Open Trash, click "Empty": "The operation can’t be completed because the item “iOS 7.1.simruntime” is in use"
2. Terminal:

```
mba7:.Trash fsc$ rm -rf iOS\ 7.1.simruntime
rm: iOS 7.1.simruntime/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK7_1.bom: Operation not permitted
rm: iOS 7.1.simruntime/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK7_1.plist: Operation not permitted
rm: iOS 7.1.simruntime/System/Library/Receipts: Operation not permitted
rm: iOS 7.1.simruntime/System/Library: Directory not empty
rm: iOS 7.1.simruntime/System: Directory not empty
rm: iOS 7.1.simruntime: Directory not empty
mba7:.Trash fsc$
```

3. Terminal: "sudo"

```
mba7:.Trash fsc$ sudo rm -rf iOS\ 7.1.simruntime
... same error
```

4. "lsof" (output manually wrapped)

```
mba7:.Trash fsc$ sudo lsof | grep "simruntime"
com.apple 743            root  txt       REG                1,4     
58608            21307311 /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/
iOS 8.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib
```

I already restarted several times, tried to change permissions etc.

What other steps can I take to get rid of the files?

Comment: Xcode or simulator are running when your a trying to delete ? Did you tried to " $ sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/* " ?

Comment: @MrMojoRisin No Xcode and no simulator is running. Yes, I tried sudo rm - same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP).

- Reboot the Mac in Recovery mode : Hold down Command + R after you hear the startup chime
- Launch the terminal (Utilities > Terminal)
- csrutil disable
- Reboot
- Empty your trash
- Reboot again in Recovery mode
- Launch the terminal
- csrutil enable
- Reboot

Comment: Please make sure you file a radar, capturing as much state as you can, before doing this.  This is likely a bug in SIP as you should be able to remove those receipts.